# How to create a Maven-compatibile repository from a bunch of JAR-files?

Tags: java, maven, repository, pom.xml

I'm maintaining an application, that uses a multitude of JAR-files -- some its own, some open-source -- which are already available to the application's own components via HTTP.

Some of these JARs are necessary for developing *client*-applications talking to the application, and we'd like to use the already-present HTTP-server instead of loading the same JARs into Nexus or similar service.

It is my understanding, that, in addition to the actual JARs, Maven requires a `.pom` file with additional details for each JAR -- and we can place these `.pom` files next to the JARs, so that the built-in HTTP-server will serve them just as well.

But how would we *generate* these files in the first place? Preferably, with the inter-dependency information recorded too?

Comment: Are you already building with Maven?

Comment: Yes, we are -- but the need to use the application's own JARs is new. Instead of stuffing them into Nexus, we'd like Maven to download them at build-time directly from the application's own HTTP-server.

Comment: Please explain more in detail what exactly you are doing and what you like to do...

Comment: I want Maven to download certain JARs from the application's own fileserver.

Comment: The application is built by Maven correct? Why do you like to download jars from the application own fileserver? Sounds like an chicken and egg problem...but I suppose I don't understand what you really like to do and more important why you like to do this? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The application comes from a vendor. We're developing our little clients for it. The clients need some of the application's own JARs at build-time (and then at run-time).

Comment: @MikhailT. check if download plugin can help you https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin

Comment: Thanks, @YuriG. - this approaches the problem from the other end: download the JARs without POMs. I'm still curious, if I can add the POM-files, so regular Maven can work with the JARs unaided by plugins...

Comment: I think no, because you will need to maintain this like a maven repo. I think it’s easier to set up an internal nexus instance and to upload the files there

Comment: There is nothing to maintain really - they come with the application and never change. The application itself is upgraded once in 3-5 _years_...

Comment: You need to implement the maven repo layout https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final

Comment: Ok, is there some tool already available, perhaps, that will let me create such a layout -- based on the existing collection of JAR-files?

Comment: I'm not familiar with such tools, except existing repository managers like nexus, artifactory etc..